# Run Batch Builds in CodeBuild using a single buildspec file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

This is the buildspec format for build-list in CodeBuild

```yaml
version: 0.2

batch:
  fast-fail: false
  build-list:
    - identifier: build1
      env:
        variables:
          BUILD_ID: build1
      ignore-failure: false
    - identifier: build2
      buildspec: build2.yml
      env:
        variables:
          BUILD_ID: build2
      ignore-failure: true
```

Instead of giving another buildspec(build2.yml)I want to specify the commands directly in a single file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the inline yaml syntax instead of passing the filename.
Something like this:

```
version: 0.2
batch:
  fast-fail: false
  build-list:
    - identifier: build1
      env:
        variables:
          BUILD_ID: build1
      buildspec: |
        version: 0.2
        env:
          shell: bash
        phases:
          build:
            commands:
              - command
      ignore-failure: true

    - identifier: build2
      env:
        variables:
          BUILD_ID: build2
      buildspec: |
        version: 0.2
        env:
          shell: bash
        phases:
          build:
            commands:
              - command
      ignore-failure: true
```

Answer (score 1):

`buildspec` is an optional property of `batch/build-list`, from the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/batch-build-buildspec.html#build-spec.batch.build-list):

> If this parameter is not specified, the current buildspec file is used.

So you can add phases to the buildspec as you would for a non-batch build, [example from the userguide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-pipeline-batch.html):

```
batch:
  build-list:
    - identifier: build1
      env:
        compute-type: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
    - identifier: build2
      env:
        compute-type: BUILD_GENERAL1_MEDIUM

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - echo 'file' > output_file

artifacts:
  files:
    - output_file
```